# getJSON not working correctly with codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, json, codeigniter

I am trying to implement AJAX call method into my website using codeigniter, the reason why i want to use AJAX so i can get live updates from the database

The click button works and displays all of the JSON data but the issue is when i try and display a specific array it does not recognize it, it seems to be iterating through every single character.

Also another wierd thing is when the alert is being called i can see the html and head tags I want to be able to print specific arrays for example the array id"

Things i have done to try and work it out

- i have alerted the datatype and found out it was a string
- i have managed to get ajax to work in regular PHP rather then codeigniter so their is nothing wrong with the database
- I have also tried to use jQuery.parseJSON so i can force it to be json but then the script did not run
- I used JSONlint and apprently its a valid JSON

Any help would be appreciated

Consolelog

```
<html>
    <head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAXpGbk1wkkaPiv_qkBevxAP9s4kk0oiiU&sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

[
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "postcode": "NW6",
        "imgurl": "hello.jpeg",
        "from_user": "henny",
        "created_at": "2013-03-18 23:03:00"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "postcode": "NW2",
        "imgurl": "test.jpeg",
        "from_user": "belly",
        "created_at": "2013-03-15 23:03:00"
    }
]
]
```

Controller

```
public function insertJSON()
{
    $this->load->model("values");
    $queryresults = $this->values->getDb();

    $arrays = array($queryresults);

    echo json_encode($arrays);  
}
```

View

```
<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>

  $('#getdata').click(function (data) {

      $.ajax({

          url: '<?php echo base_url().'index.php/welcome/insertJSON';?>',
          type: 'POST',
          cache: 'false',
          datatype: 'json'

      }).done(function (data) {

         alert(data);

      });

  });

</script>
```

json_encode

```
[
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "postcode": "NW6",
        "imgurl": "hello.jpeg",
        "from_user": "henny",
        "created_at": "2013-03-18 23:03:00"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "postcode": "NW2",
        "imgurl": "test.jpeg",
        "from_user": "belly",
        "created_at": "2013-03-15 23:03:00"
    }
]
]
```

Comment: `console.log(data)` rather than `alert(data)` will give you a much better look at what is being returned.

Comment: updated the code with the consolelog

Comment: Try using [.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) instead of the more generic `.ajax()` method.

Comment: The console.log() appears to have other HTML in it, along with your encoded json response. Is this the case? If you're retrieving json, your only output should be json, not mixed with anything else.

Comment: yea thats the case its displaying other HTML and im not sure how to only grab JSON i thought i was doing it right

Comment: Well what is generating that HTML? Did you extend the view loader, or have a base controller or other call to `$this->load->view()` that is creating the HTML?

Comment: i changed the $autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'file'); to $autoload['helper'] = array('file'); and now its not displaying anything when i try and call the JSON

Comment: That's because you've just disabled the use of the `base_url()` function. Autoloading a helper isn't going to generate HTML in your views. You need to figure out where that HTML is being generated and disable it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send the correct response headers back (application/json) from your controller function.

Try changing your controller to the following:

```
public function insertJSON()
{
    $this->load->model("values");
    $queryresults = $this->values->getDb();

    $arrays = array($queryresults);

    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')
                 ->set_output(json_encode($arrays));
}
```